# Google Analytics - Account name lost

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, account

Good afternoon,

I just started with a new company and need to remodel our website. Within the Code their is a tracking ID for Google Analytics, but unfortunately nobody can remember what the account names are. Is there any way that I could use my tracking ID, which includes my Account number according to my research, to get to my account name?

Thank you very much to everybody who is putting in some effort to help me.

jonny.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: If you don't have access to the account though the website, and no one else at the company does either, you are stuck there is no way for you to find out who the original owner is.   You will probably need to create a new account and consider your data lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Analytics Account Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) to search for all accounts you have access to.

If you have access to this account, you'll be able to find the account name by searching with the tracking ID. If nothing shows up, find someone you know has access and have them search.

Comment: It sounds like he just started at the company and he doesn't have access if no one knows who the owner of the account is, I think it is safe to assume he doesn't have access to the account in question.   The account explorer isn't going to tell you who is the owner if you are only a user you don't get access to the other users either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. Looks like my data is lost and I'm just gonna have to live with it. I hope it works out somehow. Again. Thank you very much for your time and help.